# How do I test if my variable is not in a set?

Tags: shell, files, scripting, set

I am trying to modify the bash shell script and need some assistance.

I have a directory with a bunch of files. What I need is to go through the files in a loop and if the file name not in a specific set of file names, change the file permission and mode.

Something like this:

```
for my_file in `ls my_dir/*.so`
do
   if [ $myy_file ! in ["a.so", "b.so"]]; then
      chmod 777 $my_file
      chown igor $my_file
   fi
done
```

It is much easier to check for couple of files not in the set. Then compare for the name in the big set of file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to process hidden files:

```
for f in  my_dir/*.so; do
  case $f in
    (*/[ab].so) : ;;
    (*) chmod 777 -- "$f"; chown igor -- "$f" ;;
  esac
done
```

Note that setting file permission to *777* is very bad ideal, causing security hole and making `chown` command later wasted.

Comment: I ended up using case statements. It was very easy to write. Problem was - we have an interesting naming conventions for the files in the company and so I had to spell out all my exception cases, No big deal though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can avoid your if looping structure by:

```
chmod 777 -- my_dir/[^ab].so my_dir/*??.so
chown igor -- my_dir/[^ab].so my_dir/*??.so
```